# How many additional numbers can I set in one contact?

Tags: contacts

How many additional numbers can I set in one contact?

I was playing around with a script and I was able to get only 400 of them in on a simulator. However, I would like some official response about what is the maximum, and does it vary based on the Android version.

Comment: We probably need to go into the source code to see it, which is off-topic for here.

Comment: Yeah, thought I might get this kind of a reply. Will post in StackOverflow then. Thanks.

Comment: Meh, I ended up deleting it there as honestly some people really are as they say 'so police'

Comment: @SarpSTA That's nonsense. We have many questions that have been answered by examining the Android source. It doesn't matter how you get the answer, just whether it's interesting and relevant to non-developers.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? It's pretty unlikely a single person has several hundreds of phone numbers.

Comment: @Nikola Don't worry. One random user doesn't decide what's on- and off-topic on this site: we all decide together, as a community.

Comment: @Izzy: say you have one 'spam contact' that you keep filling with spam numbers that come your way - that's the use case and problem I'm solving.

Comment: Good point. Maybe you [edit] your question and add that? With that detail, you might have described an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154). Isn't your real question rather "how to block hundreds of spam numbers effectively" – and would you also accept solutions other than adding them to your contact list?

Comment: Well, not to drag this convo any further down the rabbit hole; I do know how to make that programmatically, I was just looking for some official docs which would tell me the limitations (at least some rough numbers), if they exist. Thanks for your kind help guys, as it seems this really varies from version to version and make to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarifying on your [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155897/how-many-additional-numbers-can-i-set-in-one-contact#comment199947_155897) asking for a rough estimate, it is **499** and that seems to be not *rough* but pretty much fixed . [Source- from SE webapps- What is the maximum number of phone numbers per one contact in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74240/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-phone-numbers-per-one-contact-in-gmail)

It is relevant in the sense ultimately your contacts are going to be synced using Gmail , while the Android capacity may be more or less, it doesn't matter and by the same logic Android version shouldn't either